# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" even when script part is at the end

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

I'm trying to display in a div different text based on 2 values comparison:

```
 <dom-module id="my-view1" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
 <template is="dom-bind" id="transparent-template">

<iron-ajax auto url="http://localhost:8808/datal4/" handle-as="json" last-response="{{top}}"></iron-ajax>


  <vaadin-grid id="transparent-header" items="[[top.top]]" size="10" >
  <vaadin-grid-column width="50px" flex-grow="0">
    <template class="header">#</template>
    <template><div>{{displayIndex(index)}}</div></template>
  </vaadin-grid-column>
      <vaadin-grid-column resizable>
        <template class="header">Evolution</template>
        <template><div id="div_id">{{changeimg(item.score, item.oldscore)}}</div></template>

      </vaadin-grid-column>

    </vaadin-grid>
   </template>
  </body>
  <script>

 Polymer({
     is: 'my-view1',
      changeimg: function(score, oldscore) {

        var imagid = document.getElementById('div_id');

        if( score>oldscore ){imagid.innerHTML = "bigger";}
        else if(score<oldscore){imagid.innerHTML ="smaller";}
        else {imagid.innerHTML = "equal";}

     }  </script>
```

In the console I have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" and on the page only first cell from the grid is filled in with the wrong value (equal - when it should be smaller) 
I read about same issues all over the internet before posting here but I really don't know what I did wrong...

Comment: ID's should be unique. You are using same id for all div.

Comment: Any advice on how to solve it? Using class and document.getElementsByClassName instead also didn't work...

Comment: in the end it worked with div id="div_id_[[index]]" and then using it also in the function: var imagid = document.getElementById("div_id_"+index); Thanks!

Comment: That’s great. It is not hard.

Comment: I decided to get rid of the vaadin element. Now I use dom-repeat but the id+index is not working anymore. I know I have to use this.$$ and async function but it's not clear... I'm quite new to these. I was not able to find an a-z example....

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a reference to any element at all because data binding provides the effect you seek. You could simply return the desired text from the `changeimg()` binding:

```
changeimg: function(score, oldscore) {
  if (score > oldscore) {
    return "bigger";
  } else if (score < oldscore) {
    return "smaller";
  } else {
    return "equal";
  }
}
```

For the following template. the return value of `changeimg()` is shown as the text content of the `<div>`:

```
<div>{{changeimg(item.score, item.oldscore}}</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vepYda?editors=1010)

Comment: Indeed, from a practical perspective this could be solved like that but I want to solve this particular/theoretical case - because actually I'm looking for a way of displaying a different picture based on that comparison (green arrow, red arrow...) so it should be like: document.getElementById("blaah").src="blaah"; Of course, I had same error with this. But I think Ofisora is right -I'm using same id for all divs in the loop.